# How to give a height to the PopUpMenuButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, popupmenu

I am trying to create a`PopupMenuButton`.I have used the `PopupMenuButton class`.

```
PopupMenuButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
  offset: Offset(-16, 0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.orange,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(16.0),
        )),
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 12.0),
    child: Text(
      "Category",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
  itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
    new PopupMenuItem<String>(
        //I want this context to be scrollable with some fixed height on the screen
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
            Text("Dairy & Bakery")
          ],
        ),
        value: '1'),
  ],
)
```

I have tried implementing the `PreferredSizeWidget` but is not working on `PopupMenuButton`.

Comment: add height property to the Conrainer element

Comment: BTW, I suggest you change the question title to "How to give a height to the PopUpMenu in Flutter?"

Comment: I suggest you Implement what you need from scratch using `ListView`

Comment: How will I show that like I want

Answer (score 5):

Edit: i meant fixed height :S

PopUpMenuButton does not support a fixed height. But what u can do is adjust the PopUpMenu Package.
Something similar is done 
[here](https://gist.github.com/DhytoDev/cdadf2e78bd694192c65b5634c2ad53e)
with the DropdownButton. For the PopUpMenu the implemenatition should work analogously, as both have the same strucktur. (Route, RouteLayout and PopUpMenu)

#### Edit:

You take a look at the the [original code of the DropdownButton](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b712a172f9/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L581) and then look at the changes the person did to it in [the custom edition](https://gist.github.com/DhytoDev/cdadf2e78bd694192c65b5634c2ad53e).

Then you take the [code of the PopUpMenuButton](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b712a172f9/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart#L818) and copy them into your own project and adjust them like it was done with the DropDownButton.

Then you use ure custom version of the PopUpMenuButton with the argument height.

#### Edit 2:

As you had some problems doing what I meant, I did it for you:
Just copy this [file](https://github.com/Menelphor/CustomPopUpMenuButton/tree/master) into your directory and import it into your code.
Then use CustomPopupMenuButton with a height instead of the original one.

Usage:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'custom_popup_menu_button.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

enum WhyFarther { harder, smarter, selfStarter, tradingCharter }

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  WhyFarther _selection;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'it does work here',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: CustomPopupMenuButton<WhyFarther>(
        onSelected: (WhyFarther result) {
          setState(() {
            _selection = result;
          });
        },
        height: 100,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<WhyFarther>>[
          const PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
            value: WhyFarther.harder,
            child: Text('Working a lot harder'),
          ),
          const PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
            value: WhyFarther.smarter,
            child: Text('Being a lot smarter'),
          ),
          const PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
            value: WhyFarther.selfStarter,
            child: Text('Being a self-starter'),
          ),
          const PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
            value: WhyFarther.tradingCharter,
            child: Text('Placed in charge of trading charter'),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

If anything is not working feel free to ask, perhaps I will look into it later.

Comment: PopupMenuButton support scrollable content, Because when the content inside the popupmenu becomes too big to fit in the device screen, it becomes scrollable

Comment: i meant fixed height :S... This is what is implemented in the custom drop down button